# In *nix, what causes "sleeping" in top command?

Tags: php, linux, unix, process, top-command

What causes these `sleeping` processes that I see in `top`? If I were to call PHP's `sleep()` function, would that add to the `sleeping` count I see in `top`? Are there any disadvantages to having a high number in `sleeping`?

Comment: The processes is sleeping because they have nothing to do at the moment.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

A process is sleeping when it is blocked, waiting for something.  For example, it might have called `read()` and is waiting on data to arrive from a network stream.

`sleep()` is indeed one way to have your process sleep for a while.  Sleeping is, however, the normal state of all but heavily compute-bound processes - sleeping is essentially what a process does when it isn't doing anything else.  It's the normal state of affairs for most of your processes to be sleeping - if that's *not* the case, it tends to indicate that you need more CPU horsepower.

Answer (score 11):

A sleeping process is like suspended process.
A process sleeps when:

1. It's doing an I/O operation (blocking for I/O)
2. When you order it to sleep by sleep()

The status of any process can be:

- Ready: when it ready for execution and it's in the queue waiting the processor call with specific priority
- Sleeping: When it was running and it was blocked for I/O operation or when executing sleep()
- Running: When the processor executes a process it becomes running.

Status Meaning

- R Runnable
- T Stopped
- P Waiting on Pagein
- D Waiting on I/O
- S Sleeping < 20 seconds
- I Idle - sleeping >20 seconds
- Z Zombie or defunct

Answer (score 2):

They are processes which aren't running on the CPU *right now*. This is not necessarily a bad thing.

If you have huge numbers (10,000 on a server system, for example) of processes sleeping, the amount of memory etc used to keep track of them may make the system less efficient for non-sleeping processes.

Otherwise, it's fine.

Most normal server systems have 100 to 1000 much of the time; this is not a big deal.

Just because they're not doing anything just now doesn't mean they won't, very soon. Keeping them in memory, ready, reduces latency when they are required.

Answer (score 2):

To go into a bit more detail here, the `S` state means the process is waiting on a timer or a slow device, while the `D` state means it is waiting on a fast device.

What constitutes a fast device vs a slow device is not terribly well defined, but generally, all serial, network, and terminal devices are slow devices, while disks are fast devices.